# Trouble identifying error in fake-proof.

Tags: complex-numbers, exponentiation, fake-proofs

I was talking to a friend about the problem with this proof and I'm stomped on the illegal step:

$i = (-1)^{(1/2)}= (-1)^{(2/4)} =((-1)^2)^{(1/4)} = 1^{(1/4)} = 1$

Comment: Search tip: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/fake-proofs?tab=Frequent

Comment: @Gary: Your statement is very misleading, as the issue has nothing to do with complex numbers...

Answer (score 0):

This is wrong for the same reason that the following proof is wrong:
$$-1 = (-1)^{(2/2)} = (-1^2)^{(1/2)} = 1^{(1/2)} = 1$$
1 is $a$ 'square root of unity', but it's not unique.